# GDAL in global silent mode

Tags: gdal

Is there a way to run `gdal` commands in a silent and quiet mode, for instance, for command tools such as `gdalmdimtranslate`? a global configuration perhaps? Other commands tools such as `gdalwarp` have the `-q` option, for example.

Any pointers are welcomed,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. As you've noticed, some GDAL commandline tools support a `-q` flag, but not all. There's no `-q` or `--quiet` type flag in the arguments common to all GDAL [raster](https://gdal.org/programs/raster_common_options.html) and [vector](https://gdal.org/programs/vector_common_options.html) commandline tools.  Nor is there a [config option](https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html#list-of-configuration-options-and-where-they-apply) that controls this (see also the old list of [config options](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions)).

However, there's a standard way to run *any* commandline program in silent mode and that's to use [output redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirect_(computing)) to send any output to somewhere other than the terminal. That 'somewhere' can be a file or into the black hole that is `/dev/null` (Linux/MacOS) or `NUL` (Windows).

If you just want to silence the standard output but still show errors:

```
# Linux/MacOS
gdalmdimtranslate in.nc out.nc -array "name=temperature,transpose=[2,1,0]" > /dev/null

REM Windows
gdalmdimtranslate in.nc out.nc -array "name=temperature,transpose=[2,1,0]" > NUL
```

If you don't want to see anything, even if there's an error:

```
# Linux/MacOS
gdalmdimtranslate in.nc out.nc -array "name=temperature,transpose=[2,1,0]" > /dev/null 2>&1

REM Windows
gdalmdimtranslate in.nc out.nc -array "name=temperature,transpose=[2,1,0]" > NUL 2>&1
```